# Changing SRC attribute of IFRAME on load does not work

Tags: javascript, html, src

I wanna change `src` attribute of my `iframe` tag while loading the page:

```
<script>    
    function replaceSrc()
    {
        document.getElementByTag("iframe").src="new_link";  
    }

        window.onload = function()
    {
         replaceSrc();
    }

</script>
```

This, however does not work for me. Any suggestions? I went hrough other similar answers, but none of them is dealing with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getElementByTag()` method in JavaScript. There is [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) which returns a `NodeList` of elements. If we assume that your `<iframe>` is the first on the page, then use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "new_link";
```

Comment: Still does not work, my iframe tag is defined like this: <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autohide=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> so I have applied document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[4].src = "new_link" but it does not work.

Comment: @MichalB Why is it `4`? In your case you simply could use `document.getElementById("ytplayer").src = ...`.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is gonna be somewhere else, check here if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649807/my-javascript-function-is-influenced-by-another-js-function-already-defined